# c++ boost serialization with stringstream

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, binary

I am new to boost and c++ and is attempting to serialize an object to binary and then unserialize it.

I'm using the classes from the example in: http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/serialization.html

So suppose this is the class I am trying to serialize:

```
class person 
{ 
public: 
  person() { } 

  person(int age) : age_(age) {  } 

  int age() const { return age_; } 

private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;

  template <typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    ar & age_;
  }

  int age_;
};
```

This is the serialization code:

```
const char * save(Object ss)
{
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
    person p(31);
    oa << p;

    return ss.str().data();
}
```

This is the unserialization code:

```
void load(const char * str)
    {

        stringstream s;
        s << str;

        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(s);
        person p;
        ia >> p;
        std::cout << p.age() << std::endl;

    }
```

When I attempt to run this code, I receive this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  stream error
```

Which brings me to ask, is there a proper way of doing this?

Thanks, much appreciated.

EDIT:
This version works:

This is the serialization code:

```
string save()
{
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
    person p(31);
    oa << p;

    return ss.str();
}
```

This is the unserialization code:

```
void load(string str)
    {

        stringstream s;
        s << str;

        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(s);
        person p;
        ia >> p;
        std::cout << p.age() << std::endl;

    }
```

EDIT2:
This version does not work. Would appreciate comments on a fix. Thanks.

```
void Serialization::save()
{
    stringstream ss;
    {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
        person p(31);
        oa << p;
     }


        const char * temp1 = ss.str().data();

        stringstream s;
        s << temp1;

        cout << "UNSERIALIZING\n";
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(s);
        person p1;
        ia >> p1;
        std::cout << p1.age() << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using binary archives with `std::stringstream` is allowed, as any character can be stored in a `std::stringstream`/`std::string`.

The problem is passing around the resulting data as a null terminated C-string, as binary data is highly likely to have embedded nulls thus upon load your data will be truncated. Additionally, your save function is returning data pointing into a destroyed object, invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you elaborate on "data pointing into a destroyed object"? I assumed the data is destroyed when the function ends. So I returned the const char * data before the function ended and stored it in a variable outside save() then passed it into load(). I'm guessing my logic is wrong since the program errors.

Comment: The pointer returned by `std::string::data()` is only valid until the `string` is modified or destroyed. The `string` returned by `std::stringstream::str()` is destroyed upon completion of the `return` statement. Thus whoever is calling your `save` function will get a pointer to invalid data 100% of the time.

Comment: Ah I see. Can you recommend a better approach or a way of passing around the data without embedding nulls?

Comment: I've attempted to combined both my save() and load() into a single function called serialize() (Post is edited above with code snippet). If I understand correctly, the stringstream should be destroyed at the end of the function so the std::string::data() should still be valid throughout the function. Why does it still result in an error? Thanks.

Comment: @user459811 : Binary data will have embedded nulls. The key point is to pass around data with a data structure that wont truncate the data when there are embedded nulls. `std::vector<char>` is the obvious candidate, though technically `std::string` will work as well as long as you don't use its `data` or `c_str` methods.

Comment: @user459811 : In your revised code, the `binary_oarchive` must go out of scope before you attempt to read from `ss`. Create an artificial scope using extra braces. Also, your revision doesn't show where `ss` is defined -- where is `ss`?

Comment: I've altered my code snippet once again with a revised version. With your suggestion, I used strings instead of a const char * and it works perfectly, thanks! The only problem I have now is sending that string over activemq results in it altering the string somehow but I diverge. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ildjarn I'm sorry but going back to what you said earlier about the extra braces, I still dont quite understand. If I added artificial scope, i would allow binary_oarchive to go out of scope. I can then access the read operation. I've added the code snippet above labelled under EDIT2. ss is a local variable.

Comment: @user459811 : The extra braces should be around the direct creation and usage of `oa`, not around the code following usage of `oa`. The goal is to get `oa` to go out of scope before you read the data out of `ss`.

Comment: A stream error still occurs. Does it have something to do with storing the const char * with the operator <<?

Comment: @iser459811 : Ah, yes, that's it. Change `const char * temp1 = ss.str().data();` to `std::string const& temp1 = ss.str();`.

Comment: Is there a way to place it into a vector<unsigned char>? It appears a size is needed in order to do so but because of the embedded nulls, I'm unable to obtain a size from the string. Thanks for your patience in answering my questions.

Comment: @user459811 : `std::string::size()` is accurate regardless of embedded nulls, quite the same as `std::vector<unsigned char>::size()`. In any case, if you **really** want to, given `std::string str`, you can construct a `std::vector<unsigned char>` as follows: `std::vector<unsigned char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());`.

Answer (score -3):

You can't use binary_iarchive/binary_oarchive with stringstream, because some 'binary' characters are NOT allowed inside a 'string'. If you want use stringstream, you need 'text_iarchive/text_oarchive' or 'xml_iarchive/xml_oarchive'.

With 'binary_{io}archive' (performance) you must use a 'fstream'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my code such that it no longer uses string but const char * instead so that I can still use a stringstream. However, it is still giving me errors. Any point in the right direction is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Binary" characters are indeed allowed inside `std::string`s. Say it with me -- a `char` is a `char` is a `char`, there is no difference between 'binary' and 'text' other than context.